# How do I implement Neumann series iteration to approximate Ax = b?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix, iteration

I am working on MatLab problems from my textbook and one of the problems (as an example of Neumann series iteration) asks me to follow the pseudocode below:

```
INPUT: A n x n matrix, b n x 1 vector, T a positive integer
OUTPUT: An approximation y of x after T iterations

STEP 1: Set y = zeros(n,1)
STEP 2: Set M = eye(n) - A
STEP 2: For i = 1,2,...,T do STEP 3
   STEP 3: Set y = M*y + b
STEP 4: OUTPUT(y)
```

I am trying to find the smallest value of T such that the largest entry of the vector A*y - b in absolute value is less than the tolerance I set (the variable e as shown below). I then save T and E (the largest entry in absolute value of A*y - b).

```
function [T,E] = neumann(A,b,e)
    n = size(A);
    y = zeros(n(1,1),1);
    M = eye(n(1,1)) - A;
    t = 10000;

    for ii = 1:t
        y = M*y + b;

        if max(abs(A*y - b)) < e
            T = t;
            E = max(abs(A*y - b));
            break
        end
    end
end
```

```
A = [1.1,.2,-.2,.5;
     .2,.9,.5,.3;
     .1,0.,1.,.4;
     .1,.1,.1,1.2];
b = [1;0;1;0];

[T_2, E_2] = neumann(A,b,1e-2);
[T_4, E_4] = neumann(A,b,1e-4);
[T_6, E_6] = neumann(A,b,1e-6);
output = [T_2, E_2; T_4, E_4; T_6, E_6];
```

Instead of getting the smallest possible T, the for loop goes through all of the iterations even though I used the break statement to end the loop's execution once the condition was met. I can't really figure out what's wrong with my loop. I followed the pseudocode as closely as possible. Any feedback or suggestions is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Int this code, when the `break` is reached, the function returns, it does not iterate more. I can not reproduce what you say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always set `T = t`, you've perhaps forgotten what `t` is.

You define `t = 10000` on line 5 of the `neumann` function, this doesn't change so your output `T` is always `10000`.

Instead, I assume you wanted `T = ii;`, as `ii` is the current time step when the threshold is reached.